# How to handle SMTP email verification at scale without getting IPs blocked or SMTP requests rejected?

Tags: smtp, email-validation

I hope this question is not completely off-topic.

I've been wondering about SMTP email verification. There are so many services (e.g. Kickbox.io, Email-Validator.net, etc.) that seem to handle SMTP verification without having their IPs blocked or SMTP requests rejected.

As far as I know there is still no other method than to use the SMTP "VRFY" command, and to abort the connection once the target SMTP server has confirmed the existence of the requested user on the given mail server. I've been playing around with a few PHP scripts that claim to do this, but I keep being rejected by some mail servers, especially hotmail (as well as all other Microsoft mail services) seem to be very quickly in rejecting "spammy" SMTP requests.

Now, my question is: How is it possible that services like the ones I mentioned above process thousands of email addresses a day and validate them via what they call "SMTP handshakes", and don't see similar issues like the ones I described?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I'd not do it... first, as you noticed, it may be perceived as spamming or fishing for user data. Second, there is no guarantee that the email address remains valid between when you check and when you actually try to send.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this question?

Comment: Just in case someone else has this same problem (question is old), here an answer: the reason why many SMTP servers will block these kinds of commands is because this is exactly what spammers do, they love to have valid email addresses and want to query SMTP servers for valid addresses. SMTP servers do not like this and so most of them will block this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the companies you mention send the email to be verified as part of the `RCPT TO` command. Most domains will respond to this command with an error if the address is invalid. No email needs to actually be sent. Paid email verification services like Kickbox typically combine a well-respected email sending network that can handshake with many servers with some smart caching in order to achieve their results.

Answer (score 1):

As bwest says, `RCPT TO` is what you want to use, and `VRFY` is not usually supported even though it's performing the same check.

On the business end, this process is often called a "ping" test, and it isn't *really* considered abusive unless you're using it for an otherwise abusive end. MX admins have the option to disable it, which is what about 1/2 to 2/3 of them seem to do in the wild. Ideally the process should go:

- Confirm the mailserver gives a truthful reply to your `RCPT TO`, as opposed to accepting them all, by testing on a known false user (gibberishasdfasdf@example.com). Don't repeat this test for every email you send or you may be rejected for too many false recipients.
- If this dummy user is accepted, give up. This mailserver isn't going to answer your question.
- If dummy user is rejected, repeat your `RCPT TO` test on the email you wish to validate. If it is accepted, it is likely good. If it is rejected (like the dummy email) it is most likely truly bad. Some servers can be a little ambiguous about their "good" response, but the bottom line is that you want to see a different response than the one you got with your dummy user.

Every server is going to be differently configured so you should not make hefty assumptions about the meanings of status codes, but you should adhere to best practices by:

- Performing this test from an IP with valid reverse DNS/PTR and MX entries (this will at least double your success)
- Throttle your attempts judiciously. Attempts that end in `RCPT TO` being accepted won't upset mailservers as much as repeat rejections, because repeat rejections are a good sign someone is harvesting emails and not validating a healthy list. Repeated tests of bad users will get you all sorts of errors about greylisting, throttling, too many bad requests, and so on, from mailservers that otherwise would have been happy to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Companies like Email-Validator.net start by analyzing the email address to see if it is syntactically valid, whether it is legal and useful (e.g. probably not postmaster) whether the domain is valid (has valid DNS records), whether the address is from a throw-away email service, and other methods of checking whether they can disqualify it immediately.

After that, they attempt to send email to the address, and check the SMTP response codes from the server.  I think this is what you meant by the "SMTP handshake" you mentioned.

VRFY is no longer a very useful method of validation because most servers don't want to expose their lists of valid addresses to spammers.  Most servers don't implement support for it, or they respond to the VRFY command with a 251 or 252, indicating that the query is legal, but they aren't going to give an informative answer.

They may also use their experience with the email service provider in question (e.g. Gmail) to evaluate what the SMTP response means.  For example, some services accept all recipient addresses as though they were valid, so they don't expose which ones are valid and which ones aren't.  If none or few of the recipients were valid, the server may later drop the connection or even accept the email but not  deliver it.  Some service providers use greylisting, which can cause valid addresses to be rejected initially.  The validation service may know about the service provider's behavior from the response, a posted policy, or from their own testing.

It's also possible that companies like kickbox.io have negotiated contracts with service providers like Microsoft Hotmail so that their queries are honored, and they can validate email addresses.  It could be in the service provider's interest to allow legitimate senders to clean their mailing lists since it reduces traffic to their servers.  However, there has to be some trust that they aren't providing validation services to spammers attempting to harvest their directory.